# Why are the minutes disabled in vue-ctk-date-time-picker?

Tags: vue.js, datetimepicker

I am using the vue-ctk-date-time-picker to display a date time picker modal where users can pick date and time. I use a minDate such that users cannot pick date and time less than the current date and time. This works perfectly with format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`, but I needed the AM and PM format so I changed the format to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a`. Now, the PM equivalent of the AM date is also being disabled.

For example, its 8:30 AM, so the picker disables all minutes upto 30 and users can only select 31, 32 and so on. But if I select PM, the minutes are still disabled, ie, the users are only able to pick from 31, when its not even PM yet.

Has anyone faced this problem? Is there a problem with package itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem, this is the solution according to the document here: https://github.com/chronotruck/vue-ctk-date-time-picker#behaviour

> In order to avoid having too much properties in the component, We're
> adding a behaviour property that is an object including some annex
> behaviour values.
>
> The default value for this object is:

```
{
  time: {
    nearestIfDisabled: true;
  }
}
```

> To override those values, pass a new object with the values you want
> to override:

```
<ctk-date-time-picker
  :behaviour="{
    time: {
      nearestIfDisabled: false
    }
  }"
/>
```